# How to use 2 sed commands in a single file as a input value?

Tags: android, shell, sed

I have 2 `sed` command in one sh file to input value for other sh file like this

```
sed -i '23 i\if [ $REPLY == '0,5120,10240,20480,40960,65536' ]; then' /system/0211/0211tr.sh
sed -i '27 i\elif [ $REPLY == '6144,12288,18432,32768,49152,57344' ]; then' /system/0211/0211tr.sh
```

First `sed` is working, but another one is not. First `sed`, insert a value in line 23, and second `sed` insert value in line 27. There is another way to make this work? I run this in Android device

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Is it by any chance that the first script increases the subsequent line numbers so the 2nd script doesn't insert where you think it will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your quotes from single quotes `'` to souble quotes `"` for the sed command, as you have single quotes `'` in the text you are inserting too.

Also once you change the quotes, you need to escape characters like `$` and `\` with a `\`.

And, you can have those two inserts into one single `sed` command.

```
sed -i -e "23 i\\if [ \$REPLY == '0,5120,10240,20480,40960,65536' ]; then"  \
       -e "27 i\\elif [ \$REPLY == '6144,12288,18432,32768,49152,57344' ]; then" \
        /system/0211/0211tr.sh
```

Comment: Never enclose any script in double quotes. It's not necessary and just adds complexity, as stated above.